# overriding JComponent methods

Tags: java, user-interface

after running this code appears windows sized 0x0.
i can fix it by writting "f.setSize(640, 480);" in the main method.
i hear its bad pratice, so.. is there way to make this overriding work?

```
public class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.add(new DrawingPad());
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
 }

class DrawingPad extends JComponent{
    Image img = new ImageIcon("res/icon.jpg").getImage();
    Dimension d = new Dimension(640, 480);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){return d;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `f.pack()` before making the frame visible.

Quote from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29):

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method.

Also, you should not use swing components from the main thread. Only from the event dispatch thread. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html